# ベーシック認証のURLにスペースを含んだユーザ名を埋め込みたい

Tags: html, http

ベーシック認証に対するユーザ名とパスワードのURLへの埋め込みは下記のとおりと
理解しております。

http://username:password@example.com

例えば、ユーザ名とパスワードにスペースや記号を含む場合に、パーセントエンコードを行って
URLに埋め込んだのですがログインできません。

例
username：AAA bbb 01
password: DdddEeeee11!

http://AAA%20bbb%2001:DdddEeeee11%21@example.com

URLが間違っていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

URLをパーセントエンコードすることに問題は無いはずです。

URLからログイン情報を抜き出し、`Authorization` ヘッダに設定するのはクライアント（ブラウザ）の役割です。使用しているクライアントが、正しくURLを解釈できているか、ログを見て確認するとよいと思います。正しく解釈されていれば、例えば以下のようなリクエストになっているはずです。

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
...
Authorization: Basic Zm9vIGJhcjpiYXp6IQ==
```

Comment: curlで確認したところ、basic認証ではなく、NTLM認証とNegotiate認証が設定されていました。  curl --ntlmではログインできるのですが、質問の方法でのログインは難しいのかなと思っています。